# VMware memory allocation process ... HUGE RESOURCE HIT?

Tags: kernel, vmware, ram

**I am writing this with concerns on the way RAM(memory) is handled by the same software(VMware Workstation) across different versions of the Ubuntu OS.**

I am however unsure if the concern i am reporting here is actually a Bug ... or ... a feature that has been withdrawn on purpose ... or ... a feature that's got overlooked from kernel to kernel updates.

**How did i stumble upon this issue ?**

My primary daily driver OS is Ubuntu 14.04 (ker. 3.13), i use VMware workstation on this host to run Windows 7 to run my work software which does not have a linux version. While my VM guest*Windows 7) has been allocated 8GB of RAM the RAM usage on my Host shows no more than 3-4GB.

I while back i had installed Ubuntu 16.04 on an adjacent partition and tried running a copy of the exact same VM guest and to my shock saw that right from boot the entire 8GB of RAM gets blocked on the host system.

What was earlier 3-4 GB of RAM consumption in Ubuntu 14.04 now shot up to a whopping 10-11GB in Ubuntu 16.04. A HUGE resource hit.

Now i am test driving Deepin OS i find the same resource hit on this OS too just like the one experienced on Ubuntu 16.04 ... 10-12 GB of RAM is affected the moment i boot up my vm machine. I am using an exact same copy from Ubuntu 14.04 to run even here.

**What additional test's have i done to probe this issue ?**

I have tested this HUGE RESOURCE HIT on the following versions ... I used the exact same version of VMware Workstation on my test OS's as well as the latest version of VMware workstation, following are the findings.

software version tested on ...

**VMware Workstation 12.1.0
VMware Workstation 14**

OS versions tested on ...

**Ubuntu 14.04 (Ker. 3.13)
Ubuntu 15.04 (Ker. 3.19)
Ubuntu 15.10 (Ker. 4.2)**

tests on the above OS's show that the memory is efficiently handled and the overall memory consumption(both Host and Guest VM included)is roughly around 4 GB even though the VM is configured with 8GB of RAM

**UbuntuGnome 16.04 (Ker. 4.4)
Deepin 15.4.1 (Ker. 4.9)
UbuntuGnome 17.04 (Ker. 4.10)**

**However my tests on these OS resulted in a HUGE RESOURCE HIT ... the overall memory consumption(both Host and Guest VM included) here has been a WHOPPING 10-12GB.**

**What proof do you have of this inconsistency ?**

[RAM Usage Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nvs9M.jpg)

I have a screenshot with the memory consumed marked side by side(can't find a way to upload the same)

I have Deepin OS 15.4.1(Ker. 4.9) and Ubuntu 14.04(Ker. 3.13) on my system ... one demonstrating the resource hog i am reporting ... and ... the other demonstrating the efficient use of system resources.

So if you require any logs or commands to be run out of both this environments to further probe this resource leakage please let me know the direct commands and i'll provide the respective outputs to help you identify the issue.

PS : I am not a geek but rather consider myself as a power user, hence direct commands to collect additional info out of the 2 environments would help.

thanks for looking.

Comment: You can upload the screenshot by attaching them in the question. Kindly edit the question with necessary info. Also have a look [here](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_performance_mem_host.html) about the VMWare RAM configuration for VM's. Even after setting the **Allow most virtual machine memory to be swapped** if you see similar behavior then probably file a bug report @ VMWare.

Comment: thanks for taking the time Ameya, but i don't think the particular setting you're pointing to is the reason, i checked on both the system, and that setting is the same **Allow some virtual machine memory to be swapped**. FYI ... I've enabled the setting you've referred as well and seems VM still blocks the entire allocated RAM on the host. **I however strongly suspect something has switched at the kernel level between Ker. 4.2 and Ker. 4.4 (Ubuntu 15.10 & 16.04)**